# How does flash handle calling a value from an array with a float?

Tags: flash

There is some flash code i'm looking at that calls a value from an array with the index being a 'number' data type that contains decimal points.

The array is 100 indexes long, and a value is being called with a changing variable in a loop, that at one point, is 5.3. How does flash handle this? Does it floor, ceiling, or round the value? No exceptions are thrown. I'm converting the code to C#, so I need to know how to handle it.

```
 var _loc8_:int = 0;
     var _loc2_:String = param1.toString();
     var _loc3_:int = _loc2_.length;
     var _loc4_:int = 10;
     var _loc5_:Number = 1;
     var _loc6_:String = "";
     var _loc7_:int = 0;
     while(_loc7_ < _loc3_)
     {
        _loc8_ = param1 % _loc4_;
        _loc8_ = _loc8_ * _loc5_;
        _loc6_ = _loc6_ + this.scoreArray[_loc8_];
        _loc4_ = _loc4_ * 10;
        _loc5_ = _loc5_ * 0.1;
        _loc7_++;
     }
```

The program runs fine in it's flash state, but I can't compile it correctly in C#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say `No exceptions are thrown` that's followed by `but I can't compile it correctly in C#`... What is the problem exactly? PS: Show your C# attempt.

Comment: Any progress / feedback? I hope you're not using obfuscated code like `_loc` in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"A value is being called... at one point, is 5.3. How does flash handle this? Does it floor, ceiling, or round the value? No exceptions are thrown. I'm converting the code to C#"*

AS3's [**Number**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html) data-type is *"a data type representing an IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point number"*.

You likely want to use C# `Double`to handle decimal fractions from Flash/AS3.

Where AS3:

```
var myNum :Number = 5.3;
```

In C#, one of these will work...

```
float myFloat = 5.3f; //# 32-bit floating-point val... Has "f" suffix
double myDouble = 5.3d; //# 64-bit floating-point val... Has "d" suffix
```